# Blender for Windows Best Practices: Blank spaces in asset names?

Tags: asset

I'm working with Blender 3.0 in Windows 11 and I notice that in naming assets--object names, material names, file names, folder paths, et al--sometimes underscores (_) are used and sometimes blank spaces ( ). Is there a preferred practice?

I know that years ago when I worked with 3ds Max it was recommended that you never use blank spaces; is there a preference for Blender? Thanks!

Comment: I personally keep avoiding special letters, spaces, semicolon and dashes. I've had issues with python addons so I keep doing that. Even in my files.

Comment: This. If you think you might eventually work some day in the future with some kind of add-on or script or third-party software, avoid spaces. Otherwises, it's a matter of preferences. You should be aware that there are some ISO standards concerning asset management, so you might also try and see what's said in these documentations